# Grid View with Horizontal scrolling in android

Tags: android, gridview

I want to show images in a gridview and want to show them in a single row. 
No of columns in the gridview will be equal to no of images. Now what I want is when the no. of images are more and taking the width more than the screen size, I want to enable horizontal scrolling to the gridview, so that the images will be visible.

How can I achieve this, please help me if you have any idea.
I have already tried Gallery widget but it is not giving me the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Library called `Two Way Grid View` You can use this `GridView` in Both Orientations (Horizontal and Vertical)

**Link to the Library**:
https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview

**Sample Usage:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.jess.ui.TwoWayGridView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#E8E8E8"
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
app:cacheColorHint="#E8E8E8"
app:columnWidth="80dp"
app:rowHeight="80dp"
app:numColumns="auto_fit"
app:numRows="auto_fit"
app:verticalSpacing="16dp"
app:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
app:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
app:scrollDirectionPortrait="vertical"
app:scrollDirectionLandscape="horizontal"
app:gravity="center"/>
```

I hope this solves your problem.

**P.S:** You can also check out the sample provided with the Library for further usage demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the functionality using `RecyclerView` with `spanCount` (number of rows in your horizontal case)

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, spancount, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

If you need Staggered behavior the use `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`

[GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html)  [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html)